# How to properly remove script i found that is causing 2 products to show in structured data - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, schema, schema.org

We are having an issue where our structured data is showing 2 products instead of one on each product page. I located the script adding the extra info - however the script was found on each individual product page and we have loads of products for woo commerce. So like 1000+ pages. Is there a setting inside WordPress to remove this schema code?

I located the schema code searching our site files using Sublime. I could remove it but i feel like that would be the wrong way to do it? Since that same script is located on ALL our product pages. Is it a setting in wordpress? I am kind of lost.

This is the schema script I am trying to remove.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "vapesocietysupply",
    "url": "https://vapesocietysupplies.com",
    "logo": "https://cdn.vapesocietysupplies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/vss-logo-sharp.png",
    "contactPoint": [
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "+1-888-978-8507",
            "contactType": "customer service"
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any help in the right direction!

Structured data analysis: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fvapesocietysupplies.com%2Fproducts%2Fglazed-donut-by-loaded-e-liquid-120ml%2F

Comment: My friend says it could be code left over from an older schema plugin we deleted. Could that be possible?

Comment: I don’t know what WordPress does, but my guess is that the second `Product` item comes from a rating plugin/widget you use. For the linked example, these would be 367 ratings with an average rating of 4.65. So the thing that’s responsible for these ratings is probably also responsible for the JSON-LD.

Comment: I didn't think WooCommerce core added the schema data until WC2.7 which isn't released yet. What files did you find the code in? I'd recommend disabling all plugins one at a time until you find the ones responsible. Looks like it has been added to the `wp_footer()` hook and/or could also be manually coded into your theme's `footer.php`, so look there as well.